# convert nested sql query to jpa/hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

We use jpa/hibernate, but we have some native query like this one.

```
  SELECT cp1.id AS customerbookid
  FROM customerbook cp1
  INNER JOIN customer cu ON cu.id = cp1.customerid
  WHERE cp1.autoRenew='Y'
    AND cp1.endTime < now()
AND
  (SELECT cp2.customerid
  FROM customerbook cp2
  WHERE cp1.customerid=cp2.customerid
    AND cp2.startTime > now() 
  ) IS NULL
```

mapping

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "customerbook")
  public class CustomerBook{

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "customerId")
private long customerId;

@Column(name = "startTime")
private Timestamp startTime;

@Column(name = "endTime")
private Timestamp endTime;

@Column(name = "autoRenew")
private Character autoRenew;
  }

  @Entity
  @Table(name = "customer")
  public class customer{
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  }
```

Is it possible to convert it to jpa?

Comment: Do you mean into JPQL?

Comment: yes JPQL. do we can use hql with jpa?

Comment: `JPA` is an `API`. `Hibernate` is one of JPA **implementations**. `HQL` is Hibernate specific language.

Comment: You will need to provide the **mapping** between your classes and tables.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your relations between Entities but might look something like this:

```
EntityManager em;

Query q = em.createQuery("select cp1 FROM customerbook as cp1
          where cp1.customerid in (select cu.id from customer as cu)
          and cp1.autoRenew='Y'
          and cp1.endTime < :now
          and cp1.customerid not in (
            select cp2.customerid FROM customerbook cp2 where cp2.startTime > :now
          )");

q.setParameter("now", Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
// return List<CustomerBook>

q = em.createQuery("select cp1.id FROM customerbook as cp1
          where cp1.customerid in (select cu.id from customer as cu)
          and cp1.autoRenew='Y'
          and cp1.endTime < :now
          and cp1.customerid not in (
            select cp2.customerid FROM customerbook cp2 where cp2.startTime > :now
          )");

q.setParameter("now", Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
// return List<Long>
```

It is important that you re-think your queries 100% in objects. SQL is meant to design tables (columns/fields) but with JPQL you think in getting objects from the database (Entities or POJOs)